# Putting variable name on the left using split and cases

Tags: cases, split

Please, see the result of this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \begin{split}
X_1^{\lambda_3 n} =  \\
\begin{cases*}
        \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (+1,0,0,...,0), \text{if } m_1 = \min\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}\\ 
        \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (-1,0,0,...,0), \text{if } m_1 = \max\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}\\ 
\end{cases*}
\end{split} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like $X_1^{\lambda_3 n} =$ to be on the left, but I got it at the top right. Exactly like this:

[image: equation]

thanks!

Comment: it would be easier to see the result of the code if you posted it in a form that people could use without further edits (and guessing needed packages) but I would guess that you do not need the outer split at all as your equation is just one line and you have no alignment points (outside the cases)

Comment: *A priori*, remove the `split` environment and the `\\ `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `split` here. It suffices to use an `align`ment to set the equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  X_1^{\lambda_3 n} = 
  \begin{cases*}
    \sqrt{(1 - \lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (+1, 0, 0, \dots, 0) & if $m_1 = \min \{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$ \\ 
    \sqrt{(1 - \lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (-1, 0, 0, \dots, 0) & if $m_1 = \max \{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  & X_1^{\lambda_3 n} = \notag \\
  & \begin{cases*}
    \sqrt{(1 - \lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (+1, 0, 0, \dots, 0) & if $m_1 = \min \{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$ \\ 
    \sqrt{(1 - \lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (-1, 0, 0, \dots, 0) & if $m_1 = \max \{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$
  \end{cases*}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. That's what I was looking for. Actually, I tried that before using split, but got some error. What is the role of the \notag command?

Comment: @htennek2k: Setting the entire structure inside an `align` numbers every line. However, you can avoid numbering of a specific line (the first one in this case) via `\notag` or `\nonumber`.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's like the \nonumber command. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`cases*` is designed to have a text mode second column, and you don't need `split` here as there is only one row to the outer equation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
X_1^{\lambda_3 n} = 
\begin{cases*}
        \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (+1,0,0,\dots,0)&if  $m_1 = \min\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$\\ 
        \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (-1,0,0,\dots,0)&if $ m_1 = \max\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$
\end{cases*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Or if you want it over two lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
X_1^{\lambda_3 n} =\\
\begin{cases*}
        \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (+1,0,0,\dots,0)&if  $m_1 = \min\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$\\ 
        \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (-1,0,0,\dots,0)&if $ m_1 = \max\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}$
\end{cases*}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your reply, but this is not what I'm looking for. I actually want two lines, one for X =, and the other one for the curly brace and the definitions above. Is there anything else I may use?

Comment: @htennek2k  strange, why a line break there? But I added  a second version

Comment: It's a matter of the available space I have for writing such equation. If I use one line only, it ends up being too long and invades the other column. That's why I wanted it the way I put the picture.. Sorry

Comment: `multline` will work, but note that nowhere before that comment had you mentioned two column mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&X_1^{\lambda_3 n} =  &&\\
&\sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (+1,0,0,...,0), \: \text{if } m_1 = \min\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \} &&\\
&       \sqrt{(1-\lambda_1) n P_1} \cdot (-1,0,0,...,0), \: \text{if } m_1 = \max\{ \hat{m}_1, \hat{m}_1' \}\\&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Here is a more simplistic version of the solution you are looking for. Of course, the other suggestions above are as good as this one.

Comment: Simplistic indeed as I find this representation lacking... What about the numbering? What about the left brace? Why use `...` when you have `\dots`? Why the trailing `&&` on lines 1-2? What the use of ``\\&&`` on the last?